# AWS Step Function indefinite execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

After an year, can the step function be restarted or is there someway to run the step function indefinitely which polls Amazon DynamoDB every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to invoke AWS Step Functions every 5 mins using the AWS SDK and Lambda functions. You can use the [Step FUnctions Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sfn/SfnClient.html) to invoke the workflow created with Step Functions.

For example, this can be done with this Java code (this can be achieved using other AWS SDK supported programming languages).

```
package com.example.stepfunctions;

// snippet-start:[stepfunctions.java2.start_execute.import]
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sfn.SfnClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sfn.model.SfnException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sfn.model.StartExecutionRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sfn.model.StartExecutionResponse;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;
// snippet-end:[stepfunctions.java2.start_execute.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class StartExecution {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           final String usage = "\n" +
                    "Usage:\n" +
                    "    <stateMachineArn> <jsonFile>\n\n" +
                    "Where:\n" +
                    "    stateMachineArn - the ARN of the state machine.\n\n" +
                    "    jsonFile - A JSON file that contains the values to pass to the workflow.\n" ;

            if (args.length != 2) {
                System.out.println(usage);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            String stateMachineArn = args[0];
            String jsonFile = args[1];
            Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
            SfnClient sfnClient = SfnClient.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                    .build();

           String exeArn = startWorkflow(sfnClient,stateMachineArn, jsonFile);
           System.out.println("The execution ARN is" +exeArn);
           sfnClient.close();
        }

        // snippet-start:[stepfunctions.java2.start_execute.main]
        public static String startWorkflow(SfnClient sfnClient, String stateMachineArn, String jsonFile) {

            String json = getJSONString(jsonFile);

            // Specify the name of the execution by using a GUID value.
            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            String uuidValue = uuid.toString();
            try {

                StartExecutionRequest executionRequest = StartExecutionRequest.builder()
                        .input(json)
                        .stateMachineArn(stateMachineArn)
                        .name(uuidValue)
                        .build();

                StartExecutionResponse response = sfnClient.startExecution(executionRequest);
                return response.executionArn();


            } catch (SfnException e) {
                System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            return "";
        }

    private static String getJSONString(String path) {

        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(path));//path to the JSON file.
            String json = data.toJSONString();
            return json;
        } catch (IOException | org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
   }
    // snippet-end:[stepfunctions.java2.start_execute.main]
 }
```

Using the Java Lambda run-time API, create a Lambda function that uses the above Java code. Once you deploy the Lambda function, you can configure it to run according to a CRON Expression. Once setup, the Lambda function will execute and it will kick off your workflow based on the Cron expression.